# Azure AD App registrations- OAuth - JWT getting generated for resource which consumer app don't have permissions to

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have 3 APIs(API1, API2, and API3) registered as apps in Azure AD.

I registered consumer app and added API1 and API2 in Settings>>"Required permissions" section.

I am generating JWT OAuth token using client_credentials grant. Below is the sample

URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token

METHOD:  POST

Body:

```
grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=dsdd-fdsff-fdsfsf-fsdfs&client_secret=fdffhlfdhsu3232hekhds9&resource=API1-AppID
```

Since I added API1 and API2 in required permission JWT is generated and returned.

But JWT also getting generated successfully for API3 even though I did not add API3 under required permissions in consumer APP registration.

What could be the problem/ or missing piece here?

Comment: Have you added API3 permssions to one of API1 or API 2 Application permissions?

Comment: That is quite funny. You could specify app permissions for your APIs per: https://joonasw.net/view/defining-permissions-and-roles-in-aad. Then even if the other API gets a token for the API, it won't contain the role claim.

Comment: Hi @WayneYang-MSFT, I didn't add API3 permission to any of API1 and API2.

Comment: Hi @juunas, thanks for your reply. I am using client_credentials grant type. So our consumer app can't specify OAuth scope or role claims in JWT API call, these only applicable to authorization_code grant type.

Comment: Yeah, you can't. But your API can specify app permissions. These do not need to be requested, they are applied if they have been granted.